# Restrict read-write access from my S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am hosting a website where users can write and read files, which are stored into another S3 Bucket. However, I want to restrict the access of these files only to my website.

For example, loading a picture.

- If the request comes from my website (example.com), I want the read (or write if I upload a picture) request to be allowed by the AWS S3 storing bucket.
- If the request comes from the user who directly writes the Object URL in his browser, I want the storing bucket to block it.

Right now, even with all I have tried, people can access ressources from the Object URL.

Here is my Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Id",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Sid",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::storage-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "http://example.com/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Additionnal informations:

- All my "*Block public access*" are unchecked [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwv29.png). (I think that the problem comes from here. When I check the two boxes about ACL, my main problem is fixed, but I got a 403 error - Forbidden - when it comes to upload files to the Bucket, another problem);
- My ACL looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mAO5.png);
- My website is statically hosted on another S3 Bucket.

If you need more informations or details, ask me.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

*This message has been written by a French speaking guy. Sorry for the mistakes*

Answer (score 2):

> "aws:Referer": "http://example.com/*

The *referer* is an http header passed by the browser and any client could just freely set the value. It provides no real security

> However, I want to restrict the access of these files only to my website

Default way restrict access to S3 resources for a website is using the [pre-signed url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). Basically your website backend can create an S3 url to download or upload an s3 object and pass the url only to authenticated /allowed client. Then your resource bucket can restrict the public access. Allowing upload without authentication is usually a very bad idea.

Yes, in this case your website is not static anymore and you need some backend logic to do so.

If your website clients are authenticated, you may use the AWS API Gateway and Lambda to create this pre-signed url for the clients.